# K Shortest Path in R: igraph

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path

I have to find the K Shortest Path,However the below code i tried gives the same path when i choose different `K` Values and the distance computed is not correct.

My dataset is `my.graph` with class `igraph`

```
dput(my.graph)
    structure(list(169, FALSE, c(22, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 114, 3, 4, 5, 
    4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 8, 110, 78, 159, 9, 159, 30, 11, 13, 
    160, 11, 66, 160, 138, 14, 13, 14, 15, 81, 16, 15, 17, 16, 17, 
    18, 18, 19, 130, 19, 62, 62, 23, 42, 22, 22, 22, 23, 24, 161, 
    24, 25, 25, 26, 64, 26, 28, 161, 29, 28, 29, 47, 48, 53, 142, 
    31, 30, 32, 31, 32, 33, 33, 34, 35, 118, 34, 36, 35, 37, 36, 
    37, 38, 39, 38, 162, 40, 39, 40, 41, 41, 42, 43, 44, 43, 44, 
    45, 45, 46, 47, 46, 47, 47, 49, 48, 49, 50, 51, 50, 52, 51, 52, 
    53, 60, 53, 54, 53, 55, 54, 56, 55, 57, 56, 57, 58, 58, 59, 59, 
    60, 60, 60, 63, 162, 62, 62, 63, 64, 65, 65, 66, 166, 68, 163, 
    164, 69, 165, 68, 70, 69, 71, 70, 71, 72, 72, 73, 112, 73, 74, 
    75, 74, 76, 75, 76, 77, 78, 77, 78, 110, 78, 79, 80, 79, 146, 
    80, 81, 82, 81, 81, 82, 137, 164, 84, 85, 84, 86, 85, 86, 87, 
    87, 164, 165, 89, 89, 90, 90, 91, 92, 91, 93, 92, 93, 94, 95, 
    94, 165, 95, 163, 97, 97, 98, 99, 98, 99, 100, 101, 100, 101, 
    102, 102, 163, 104, 166, 105, 104, 106, 105, 106, 107, 108, 107, 
    109, 108, 109, 166, 110, 110, 125, 116, 112, 113, 112, 112, 114, 
    113, 114, 115, 114, 126, 115, 116, 117, 118, 117, 119, 118, 118, 
    120, 119, 120, 121, 121, 122, 123, 122, 124, 168, 141, 123, 124, 
    125, 125, 125, 126, 140, 140, 128, 128, 129, 130, 129, 130, 130, 
    131, 131, 132, 133, 132, 134, 133, 134, 135, 135, 136, 137, 136, 
    137, 137, 139, 138, 139, 168, 143, 140, 140, 141, 142, 158, 167, 
    143, 167, 144, 145, 144, 145, 146, 146, 146, 148, 148, 149, 149, 
    150, 151, 150, 152, 151, 153, 152, 153, 154, 154, 155, 156, 155, 
    156, 157, 157, 158, 158, 158, 159, 160, 159, 160, 160, 160, 161, 
    161, 162, 162, 163, 163, 163, 164, 164, 164, 165, 165, 165, 166, 
    166, 166, 167, 167, 168, 168), c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 
    3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 7, 9, 9, 9, 8, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 10, 
    12, 12, 12, 13, 11, 13, 14, 14, 15, 14, 16, 15, 16, 17, 17, 18, 
    19, 18, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 0, 21, 20, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 25, 
    26, 25, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 10, 31, 30, 31, 
    32, 32, 33, 34, 34, 33, 35, 34, 36, 35, 36, 37, 38, 37, 38, 39, 
    38, 39, 40, 40, 21, 42, 43, 42, 43, 44, 44, 45, 46, 45, 29, 46, 
    48, 29, 48, 49, 50, 49, 51, 50, 51, 52, 53, 52, 53, 29, 54, 53, 
    55, 54, 56, 55, 56, 57, 57, 58, 58, 59, 53, 59, 61, 61, 20, 19, 
    61, 26, 64, 64, 12, 67, 67, 67, 68, 68, 68, 67, 69, 68, 70, 69, 
    70, 71, 71, 72, 72, 72, 73, 74, 73, 75, 74, 75, 76, 77, 76, 77, 
    78, 9, 78, 79, 78, 80, 79, 80, 81, 80, 14, 81, 82, 83, 83, 84, 
    83, 85, 84, 85, 86, 86, 87, 88, 88, 88, 89, 89, 90, 91, 90, 92, 
    91, 92, 93, 94, 93, 95, 94, 96, 96, 96, 97, 98, 97, 98, 99, 100, 
    99, 100, 101, 101, 102, 103, 103, 104, 103, 105, 104, 105, 106, 
    107, 106, 108, 107, 108, 109, 9, 78, 110, 111, 111, 112, 72, 
    111, 113, 112, 113, 114, 2, 115, 114, 111, 116, 117, 116, 118, 
    117, 34, 119, 118, 119, 120, 120, 121, 122, 121, 123, 123, 123, 
    122, 123, 124, 124, 110, 115, 126, 127, 127, 127, 128, 129, 128, 
    129, 19, 130, 130, 131, 132, 131, 133, 132, 133, 134, 134, 135, 
    136, 135, 136, 82, 138, 12, 138, 139, 139, 127, 126, 123, 30, 
    142, 142, 139, 143, 143, 144, 143, 144, 145, 80, 145, 147, 147, 
    148, 148, 149, 150, 149, 151, 150, 152, 151, 152, 153, 153, 154, 
    155, 154, 155, 156, 156, 157, 142, 157, 9, 159, 10, 12, 11, 159, 
    23, 27, 61, 38, 96, 67, 102, 68, 83, 87, 95, 88, 68, 67, 109, 
    103, 142, 143, 123, 139), c(3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 10, 8, 11, 9, 13, 
    12, 15, 14, 18, 16, 22, 17, 28, 25, 33, 26, 34, 32, 38, 35, 40, 
    37, 41, 39, 43, 42, 46, 44, 52, 0, 53, 51, 54, 49, 57, 55, 59, 
    58, 62, 60, 66, 63, 67, 65, 73, 24, 75, 72, 76, 74, 78, 77, 82, 
    79, 84, 80, 86, 83, 87, 85, 90, 88, 93, 89, 94, 92, 96, 95, 97, 
    50, 100, 98, 101, 99, 103, 102, 106, 104, 107, 68, 108, 105, 
    110, 69, 111, 109, 114, 112, 116, 113, 117, 115, 122, 70, 120, 
    118, 124, 121, 126, 123, 128, 125, 129, 127, 131, 130, 133, 132, 
    135, 119, 136, 134, 140, 47, 139, 48, 141, 137, 142, 61, 144, 
    143, 145, 29, 152, 147, 154, 150, 156, 153, 157, 155, 159, 158, 
    162, 160, 165, 163, 167, 164, 168, 166, 171, 169, 174, 20, 172, 
    170, 177, 175, 179, 176, 183, 36, 182, 180, 184, 181, 189, 187, 
    191, 188, 192, 190, 194, 193, 198, 197, 200, 199, 203, 201, 205, 
    202, 206, 204, 209, 207, 211, 208, 214, 213, 217, 215, 218, 216, 
    221, 219, 222, 220, 224, 223, 229, 226, 231, 228, 232, 230, 235, 
    233, 237, 234, 238, 236, 240, 19, 241, 173, 246, 161, 247, 244, 
    249, 245, 252, 6, 250, 248, 254, 251, 255, 243, 258, 256, 261, 
    81, 260, 257, 263, 259, 264, 262, 266, 265, 269, 267, 273, 268, 
    274, 270, 277, 242, 276, 275, 278, 253, 282, 281, 285, 283, 287, 
    45, 286, 284, 289, 288, 292, 290, 294, 291, 295, 293, 297, 296, 
    300, 298, 302, 185, 301, 299, 304, 31, 305, 303, 309, 279, 308, 
    280, 310, 272, 311, 71, 314, 307, 318, 316, 319, 317, 321, 178, 
    322, 320, 324, 323, 326, 325, 329, 327, 331, 328, 333, 330, 334, 
    332, 336, 335, 339, 337, 340, 338, 342, 341, 344, 312, 345, 343, 
    346, 21, 348, 23, 350, 27, 349, 30, 351, 347, 352, 56, 353, 64, 
    355, 91, 354, 138, 357, 148, 356, 212, 358, 225, 359, 149, 360, 
    186, 361, 195, 364, 151, 363, 196, 362, 210, 365, 146, 367, 227, 
    366, 239, 368, 313, 369, 315, 370, 271, 371, 306), c(3, 1, 52, 
    0, 4, 2, 7, 5, 252, 6, 10, 8, 11, 9, 13, 12, 15, 14, 18, 16, 
    22, 17, 174, 20, 240, 19, 346, 21, 28, 25, 73, 24, 348, 23, 33, 
    26, 350, 27, 145, 29, 304, 31, 349, 30, 34, 32, 38, 35, 183, 
    36, 40, 37, 41, 39, 43, 42, 46, 44, 140, 47, 287, 45, 54, 49, 
    139, 48, 53, 51, 97, 50, 57, 55, 352, 56, 59, 58, 62, 60, 142, 
    61, 66, 63, 353, 64, 67, 65, 107, 68, 110, 69, 122, 70, 75, 72, 
    311, 71, 76, 74, 78, 77, 82, 79, 84, 80, 261, 81, 86, 83, 87, 
    85, 90, 88, 93, 89, 355, 91, 94, 92, 96, 95, 100, 98, 101, 99, 
    103, 102, 106, 104, 108, 105, 111, 109, 114, 112, 116, 113, 117, 
    115, 120, 118, 124, 121, 135, 119, 126, 123, 128, 125, 129, 127, 
    131, 130, 133, 132, 136, 134, 141, 137, 354, 138, 144, 143, 152, 
    147, 357, 148, 365, 146, 154, 150, 359, 149, 364, 151, 156, 153, 
    157, 155, 159, 158, 162, 160, 246, 161, 165, 163, 167, 164, 168, 
    166, 171, 169, 172, 170, 177, 175, 241, 173, 179, 176, 182, 180, 
    321, 178, 184, 181, 302, 185, 189, 187, 360, 186, 191, 188, 192, 
    190, 194, 193, 361, 195, 198, 197, 363, 196, 200, 199, 203, 201, 
    205, 202, 206, 204, 209, 207, 211, 208, 362, 210, 214, 213, 356, 
    212, 217, 215, 218, 216, 221, 219, 222, 220, 224, 223, 358, 225, 
    229, 226, 367, 227, 231, 228, 232, 230, 235, 233, 237, 234, 238, 
    236, 366, 239, 277, 242, 247, 244, 255, 243, 249, 245, 250, 248, 
    254, 251, 278, 253, 258, 256, 260, 257, 263, 259, 264, 262, 266, 
    265, 269, 267, 273, 268, 274, 270, 310, 272, 370, 271, 276, 275, 
    309, 279, 282, 281, 308, 280, 285, 283, 286, 284, 289, 288, 292, 
    290, 294, 291, 295, 293, 297, 296, 300, 298, 301, 299, 305, 303, 
    314, 307, 371, 306, 344, 312, 368, 313, 318, 316, 369, 315, 319, 
    317, 322, 320, 324, 323, 326, 325, 329, 327, 331, 328, 333, 330, 
    334, 332, 336, 335, 339, 337, 340, 338, 342, 341, 345, 343, 351, 
    347), c(0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 18, 20, 20, 22, 
    24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 34, 34, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 46, 48, 50, 
    52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 
    84, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 102, 104, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114, 
    118, 118, 122, 124, 126, 128, 130, 130, 132, 134, 136, 138, 140, 
    142, 144, 146, 148, 150, 154, 156, 158, 162, 164, 164, 166, 168, 
    170, 172, 172, 174, 176, 178, 180, 182, 184, 186, 186, 188, 190, 
    192, 194, 196, 198, 198, 200, 202, 204, 206, 208, 210, 214, 214, 
    218, 220, 224, 226, 228, 230, 234, 236, 238, 240, 242, 244, 246, 
    250, 252, 252, 254, 256, 260, 262, 264, 266, 268, 270, 272, 276, 
    278, 280, 284, 286, 288, 290, 292, 294, 298, 298, 300, 302, 304, 
    306, 308, 310, 312, 314, 316, 318, 322, 326, 332, 336, 340, 346, 
    352, 358, 364, 368, 372), c(0, 4, 6, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 
    22, 28, 34, 38, 44, 46, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 62, 66, 70, 70, 74, 
    76, 78, 80, 84, 86, 92, 96, 98, 100, 102, 106, 108, 110, 112, 
    116, 118, 120, 120, 122, 124, 126, 128, 130, 130, 132, 134, 136, 
    138, 140, 144, 146, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 156, 160, 160, 160, 
    162, 162, 162, 168, 174, 176, 178, 180, 184, 186, 188, 190, 192, 
    194, 198, 200, 204, 206, 208, 212, 214, 216, 218, 220, 224, 226, 
    228, 230, 232, 234, 236, 238, 242, 244, 246, 248, 250, 252, 254, 
    258, 260, 262, 264, 266, 268, 270, 272, 276, 278, 280, 282, 284, 
    286, 288, 290, 292, 294, 296, 298, 304, 306, 306, 308, 312, 314, 
    316, 318, 320, 322, 324, 326, 328, 330, 330, 332, 336, 336, 336, 
    340, 344, 346, 348, 348, 350, 352, 354, 356, 358, 360, 362, 364, 
    366, 368, 370, 370, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 372, 
    372), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
        structure(list(name = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
        "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
        "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
        "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
        "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", 
        "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
        "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
        "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", 
        "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", 
        "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", 
        "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", 
        "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", 
        "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", 
        "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", 
        "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", 
        "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", 
        "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", 
        "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169"
        )), .Names = "name"), structure(list(DIST_KM_CNT = c(4.89, 
        1.45, 2.36, 1.45, 2.36, 1.18, 0, 1.18, 0.89, 1.47, 0.89, 
        1.47, 1.16, 1.16, 1.2, 1.2, 1.02, 0.79, 1.02, 0, 0, 1, 0.79, 
        0, 0.98, 1.03, 1.15, 0, 1.03, 1.35, 0.95, 0, 0.99, 1.15, 
        0.99, 1.53, 0, 1.22, 1.53, 1.37, 1.22, 1.37, 1.23, 1.23, 
        1.1, 0, 1.1, 1.38, 1.69, 3.49, 3.16, 1.38, 4.89, 1.38, 3.49, 
        1.51, 0, 1.51, 1.39, 1.39, 1.78, 0.947, 1.78, 1.17, 2.12, 
        3.26, 1.17, 3.26, 1.43, 0, 0, 15.58, 1.11, 0.98, 1.09, 1.11, 
        1.09, 1.43, 1.43, 1.15, 1.11, 0, 1.15, 1.13, 1.11, 1.96, 
        1.13, 1.96, 1.86, 2.48, 1.86, 0, 1.44, 2.48, 1.44, 2.38, 
        2.38, 3.16, 2.41, 1.691, 2.41, 1.691, 1.54, 1.54, 1.65, 4.14, 
        1.65, 1.43, 4.14, 0.572, 0, 0.572, 0.455, 0.558, 0.455, 0.54, 
        0.558, 0.54, 0.682, 0.638, 0.682, 0.42, 0, 0.624, 0.42, 0.47, 
        0.624, 0.895, 0.47, 0.895, 0.493, 0.493, 0.703, 0.703, 0.553, 
        0.638, 0.553, 4.52, 1.94, 1.69, 1.38, 4.52, 0.947, 2.647, 
        2.647, 1.35, 0, 1.66, 0, 0, 1.05, 0, 1.66, 1.31, 1.05, 1.54, 
        1.31, 1.54, 1.72, 1.72, 1.24, 0, 1.24, 0.94, 1.57, 0.94, 
        1.15, 1.57, 1.15, 0.77, 0.95, 0.77, 0.95, 0, 0, 1.38, 0.6, 
        1.38, 11.42, 0.6, 0.72, 2.64, 0.72, 0, 2.64, 0, 0.82, 0.708, 
        0.467, 0.708, 0.59, 0.467, 0.59, 0.828, 0.828, 1.047, 0.77, 
        0.517, 0.517, 0.897, 0.897, 0.727, 0.602, 0.727, 0.481, 0.602, 
        0.481, 0.726, 0.602, 0.726, 0.92, 0.602, 0.986, 0.44, 0.44, 
        0.513, 0.548, 0.513, 0.548, 0.721, 0.513, 0.721, 0.513, 0.564, 
        0.564, 0.937, 0.412, 0.576, 0.542, 0.412, 0.567, 0.542, 0.567, 
        0.497, 0.426, 0.497, 0.379, 0.426, 0.379, 0.987, 0, 0, 0.614, 
        1.321, 1.327, 0.912, 0, 1.327, 1.735, 0.912, 1.735, 1.577, 
        0, 1.188, 1.577, 1.321, 1.017, 1.057, 1.017, 1.239, 1.057, 
        0, 0.732, 1.239, 0.732, 0.877, 0.877, 1.548, 0.816, 1.548, 
        0.806, 0, 11.5, 0.816, 0.806, 0.689, 0.689, 0.614, 1.188, 
        1.357, 2.496, 1.028, 1.028, 1.432, 0.93, 1.432, 0.93, 0, 
        0.794, 0.794, 0.811, 1.395, 0.811, 1.323, 1.395, 1.323, 1.385, 
        1.385, 0.774, 1.53, 0.774, 1.53, 0, 0.841, 0, 0.841, 1.317, 
        7.75, 2.496, 1.357, 11.5, 15.58, 0.75, 0.905, 7.75, 1.317, 
        0.89, 0.593, 0.89, 0.593, 0.555, 11.42, 0.555, 1.18, 1.18, 
        0.87, 0.87, 2.63, 1.21, 2.63, 1.6, 1.21, 1.26, 1.6, 1.26, 
        1.09, 1.09, 1.12, 1.58, 1.12, 1.58, 1.42, 1.42, 0.54, 0.75, 
        0.54, 1, 1.03, 0, 0.95, 0, 1.03, 0, 2.12, 1.94, 0, 0.986, 
        0, 0.937, 0, 0.82, 1.047, 0.92, 0.77, 0, 0, 0.987, 0.576, 
        0.905, 1.317, 0, 1.317)), .Names = "DIST_KM_CNT")), <environment>), class = "igraph")
```

K Shortest Path logic

```
# find k shortest paths
k.shortest.paths <- function(graph, from, to, k){
  # first shortest path
  k0 <- get.shortest.paths(graph,from,to, output='both')

  # number of currently found shortest paths
  kk <- 1

  # list of alternatives
  variants <- list()

  # shortest variants
  shortest.variants <- list(list(g=graph, path=k0$epath, vert=k0$vpath, dist=shortest.paths(graph,from,to)))

  # until k shortest paths are found
  while(kk<k){
    # take last found shortest path
    last.variant <- shortest.variants[[length(shortest.variants)]]              

    # calculate all alternatives
    variants <- calculate.variants(variants, last.variant, from, to)

    # find shortest alternative
    sp <- select.shortest.path(variants)

    # add to list, increase kk, remove shortest path from list of alternatives
    shortest.variants[[length(shortest.variants)+1]] <- list(g=variants[[sp]]$g, path=variants[[sp]]$variants$path, vert=variants[[sp]]$variants$vert, dist=variants[[sp]]$variants$dist)
    kk <- kk+1
    variants <- variants[-sp]
  }

  return(shortest.variants)
}

# found all alternative routes
calculate.variants <- function(variants, variant, from, to){
  # take graph from current path
  g <- variant$g

  # iterate through edges, removing one each iterations
  for (j in unlist(variant$path)){
    newgraph <- delete.edges(g, j) # remove adge
    sp <- get.shortest.paths(newgraph,from,to, output='both') # calculate shortest path
    spd <- shortest.paths(newgraph,from,to) # calculate length
    if (spd != Inf){ # the the path is found
      if (!contains.path(variants, sp$vpath)) # add to list, unless it already contains the same path
      {
        variants[[length(variants)+1]] <- list(g=newgraph, variants=list(path=sp$epath, vert=sp$vpath, dist=spd))
      }
    }
  }

  return(variants)
}

# does a list contain this path?
contains.path <- function(variants, variant){
  return( any( unlist( lapply( variants, function(x){ identical(x$variant$vert,variant) } ) ) ) )
}

# which path from the list is the shortest?
select.shortest.path <- function(variants){
  return( which.min( unlist( lapply( variants, function(x){x$variants$dist} ) ) ) )
}
```

**The results are below with Same Path and and the distance computed is also not correct.I am not sure about where i am making the mistake**

```
library(igraph)
k.shortest.paths(my.graph, from = 37, to = 8, k = 2)

[[1]]
[[1]]$g
IGRAPH UN-- 169 372 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), DIST_KM_CNT (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
 [1] 1 --23  1 --2   2 --3   1 --2   2 --3   3 --4   3 --115 3 --4   4 --5  
[10] 5 --6   4 --5   5 --6   6 --7   6 --7   7 --8   7 --8   8 --9   9 --10 
[19] 8 --9   10--111 10--79  10--160 9 --10  11--160 11--31  11--12  12--14 
[28] 12--161 11--12  13--67  13--161 13--139 14--15  12--14  14--15  15--16 
[37] 15--82  16--17  15--16  17--18  16--17  17--18  18--19  18--19  19--20 
[46] 20--131 19--20  20--63  21--63  21--24  22--43  22--23  1 --23  22--23 
[55] 21--24  24--25  24--162 24--25  25--26  25--26  26--27  27--65  26--27 
[64] 28--29  28--162 29--30  28--29  29--30  30--48  30--49  30--54  31--143
+ ... omitted several edges

[[1]]$path
[[1]]$path[[1]]
+ 11/372 edges (vertex names):
 [1] 36--37  35--36  34--35  33--34  32--33  31--32  11--31  11--160 10--160
[10] 9 --10  8 --9  


[[1]]$vert
[[1]]$vert[[1]]
+ 12/169 vertices, named:
 [1] 37  36  35  34  33  32  31  11  160 10  9   8  


[[1]]$dist
    8
37 11


[[2]]
[[2]]$g
IGRAPH UN-- 169 371 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), DIST_KM_CNT (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
 [1] 1 --23  1 --2   2 --3   1 --2   2 --3   3 --4   3 --115 3 --4   4 --5  
[10] 5 --6   4 --5   5 --6   6 --7   6 --7   7 --8   7 --8   8 --9   9 --10 
[19] 8 --9   10--111 10--79  10--160 9 --10  11--160 11--31  11--12  12--14 
[28] 12--161 11--12  13--67  13--161 13--139 14--15  12--14  14--15  15--16 
[37] 15--82  16--17  15--16  17--18  16--17  17--18  18--19  18--19  19--20 
[46] 20--131 19--20  20--63  21--63  21--24  22--43  22--23  1 --23  22--23 
[55] 21--24  24--25  24--162 24--25  25--26  25--26  26--27  27--65  26--27 
[64] 28--29  28--162 29--30  28--29  29--30  30--48  30--49  30--54  31--143
+ ... omitted several edges

[[2]]$path
[[2]]$path[[1]]
+ 11/371 edges (vertex names):
 [1] 36--37  35--36  34--35  33--34  32--33  31--32  11--31  11--160 10--160
[10] 9 --10  8 --9  


[[2]]$vert
[[2]]$vert[[1]]
+ 12/169 vertices, named:
 [1] 37  36  35  34  33  32  31  11  160 10  9   8  


[[2]]$dist
    8
37 11
```

Comment: You will have a better chance of getting an answer if you post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are trying to do instead of using your entire data set.

Comment: @Bryan The dataset has 342 rows and 3 columns. This is the reduced dataset

Comment: This may be a reduced data set, but it's better to use a minimal data set. What is the simplest version of the problem that still captures the relevant elements of what you are trying to solve? Also, instead of just using `dput` to dump an `igraph` object, you might provide just a touch more context, for example, starting out width a few edges and nodes to create the `igraph` object. This will help others learn from what you are trying to do, and will make the answer more general. Finally, say what you mean by "not correct." How do you know it's not correct and what do you expect?

Comment: How can I see the summation of the weights of the links??! The result just shows the [[1]]$g, [[1]]$path, [[1]]$vert, and [[1]]$dist. The [[1]]$dist just shows the number of the nodes. I want to the value multiplied to weight. !! thank you

Answer (score 2):

I know this is like 2 years late but hopefully this will be useful for other people who needs an implementation of yen's algorithm in R.

```
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

#'@return the shortest path as a list of vertices or NULL if there is no path between src and dest
shortest_path <- function(graph, src, dest){
  path <- suppressWarnings(get.shortest.paths(graph, src, dest))
  path <- names(path$vpath[[1]])
  if (length(path)==1) NULL else path
} 

#'@return the sum of the weights of all the edges in the given path
path_weight <- function(path, graph) sum(E(graph, path=path)$weight)

#'@description sorts a list of paths based on the weight of the path
sort_paths <- function(graph, paths) paths[paths %>% sapply(path_weight, graph) %>% order]

#'@description creates a list of edges that should be deleted
find_edges_to_delete <- function(A,i,rootPath){
  edgesToDelete <- NULL
  for (p in A){
    rootPath_p <- p[1:i]
    if (all(rootPath_p == rootPath)){
      edge <- paste(p[i], ifelse(is.na(p[i+1]),p[i],p[i+1]), sep = '|')
      edgesToDelete[length(edgesToDelete)+1] <- edge
    }
  }
  unique(edgesToDelete)
}

#returns the k shortest path from src to dest
#sometimes it will return less than k shortest paths. This occurs when the max possible number of paths are less than k
k_shortest_yen <- function(graph, src, dest, k){
  if (src == dest) stop('src and dest can not be the same (currently)')

  #accepted paths
  A <- list(shortest_path(graph, src, dest))
  if (k == 1) return (A)
  #potential paths
  B <- list()

  for (k_i in 2:k){
    prev_path <- A[[k_i-1]]
    num_nodes_to_loop <- length(prev_path)-1
    for(i in 1:num_nodes_to_loop){
      spurNode <- prev_path[i]
      rootPath <- prev_path[1:i]

      edgesToDelete <- find_edges_to_delete(A, i,rootPath)
      t_g <- delete.edges(graph, edgesToDelete)
      #for (edge in edgesToDelete) t_g <- delete.edges(t_g, edge)

      spurPath <- shortest_path(t_g,spurNode, dest)

      if (!is.null(spurPath)){
        total_path <- list(c(rootPath[-i], spurPath))
        if (!total_path %in% B) B[length(B)+1] <- total_path
      }
    }
    if (length(B) == 0) break
    B <- sort_paths(graph, B)
    A[k_i] <- B[1]
    B <- B[-1]
    }
  A
}

#===================Test==========================#
edgeList <- tibble(from=character(), to=character(), weight = numeric())

edgeList[nrow(edgeList)+1,] <-list('c','d',3)
edgeList[nrow(edgeList)+1,] <-list('d','f',4)
edgeList[nrow(edgeList)+1,] <-list('f','h',1)
edgeList[nrow(edgeList)+1,] <-list('c','e',2)
edgeList[nrow(edgeList)+1,] <-list('e','d',1)
edgeList[nrow(edgeList)+1,] <-list('e','f',2)
edgeList[nrow(edgeList)+1,] <-list('e','g',3)
edgeList[nrow(edgeList)+1,] <-list('g','h',2)
edgeList[nrow(edgeList)+1,] <-list('f','g',2)

graph <- graph.data.frame(edgeList)

#k_shortest.yen(graph, 'c','c',7) #expect error
#expect all 7 paths 
k_shortest_yen(graph,'c','h',7)
```

Comment: It is very helpful to me. However, is it available to figure out the weight value of the path??! I mean the path travel time. The result only shows the traversing nodes. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and then i noticed that there are a error in the code. The function identical in function contains.path were not returning the correct value. I simply changed the code of identical(x$variant$vert,variant) to identical(unlist(x$variant$vert),unlist(variant)). And now the code is reporting all routings and no duplicates are present.

Comment: How can I see the summation of the weights of the links??! The result just shows the [[1]]$g, [[1]]$path, [[1]]$vert, and [[1]]$dist. The [[1]]$dist just shows the number of the nodes. I want to the value multiplied to weight. !! thank you